# C#: Execute the action based on the checked checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, combinatorics

There are seven checkboxes on the form that specify the following parameters:

```
1.Publish without text
2.Publish with your text
3.Publish with signature
4.Do not publish without photos
5.Do not publish without audio
6.Do not publish without video
7.Do not publish without text
```

There is also a function for which you can set some publishing options (but not all, for others there is another code). Here it is:

```
patterns.vknet.Wall.Post(new WallPostParams
{
    OwnerId = -yourcom,
    Message = yorTextBox.Text,
    Attachments = SetAttachments(),
    FromGroup = true,
    PublishDate = DateForPost()
});
```

How do a tame the complexity resulting from combining multiple options?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code.  Post _your actual code_ in the body of your question.

Comment: What will you do if they check #1 and #2 ?

Comment: @maccettura it's writes "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Is there actually a question or am I missing something?

Comment: @Behavior sounds like you shouldn't post _only_ code and maybe include a **question** in there somewhere...

Comment: How are options 1 and 7 meaningfully different? How are you handling contradicting options? What is your actual problem? How do your checkboxes meaningfully translate to the parameters in `WallPostParams`? Your question is not coherent.

Comment: Make bool publish  = ValidText && ValidVideo && ValidAudio && ValidPhoto; where each of these is like: ValidText = Text.exist || !DontOublishWithoutText( so is valid when text is set or dontPublishwithout text  is unchecked) . Then Make bools like should publishText = PublishWithText/Signature. Then just check if should publisg then create your Wall.Posts, and e.g for Message make: Message = publishText? YorTextBox.Text : null.

Answer (score -1):

Another way of solving this is to apply the conditions in the assignment expressions instead of using nested ifs. This allows you apply the conditions on each property separately:

```
patterns.vknet.Wall.Post(new WaalPostParameters
{
    onwerId = -yourcom,
    Message = yourTextCeckbox.Checked ? yourTextBox.Text : null,
    Attachemnts = <condition> ? <if true> : <if false>
    ...
});
```

you can also chain these ternary operators (?:).

```
x = c1 ? "a" : c2 ? "b" : "c"
```

Of course you could also prepare the values in advance and store them in temporary variables. This gives you the freedom of still using ifs. The point is to determine each value separately instead of assigning them in a bunch and thus avoid the combinatory problem.

---

Here an example to clarify my point. This is ...

```
if (x) {
    if (y) {
        if (z) {
            result = new Result { R = a, S = c, T = e };
        } else {
            result = new Result { R = a, S = c, T = f };
        }
    } else {
        if (z) {
            result = new Result { R = a, S = d, T = e };
        } else {
            result = new Result { R = a, S = d, T = f };
        }
    }
} else {
    if (y) {
        if (z) {
            result = new Result { R = b, S = c, T = e };
        } else {
            result = new Result { R = b, S = c, T = f };
        }
    } else {
        if (z) {
            result = new Result { R = b, S = d, T = e };
        } else {
            result = new Result { R = b, S = d, T = f };
        }
    }
}
```

... equivalent to

```
result = new Result {
    R = x ? a : b,
    S = y ? c : d,
    T = z ? e : f
};
```

Comment: "Do not publish without X" is not the same as "Do not add X when publishing". Your answer relies on omitting content, rather than halting the publish action in and of itself. Also, inlining multiple ternary operators for such a complicated scenario (and not even parentheses in the guiding example!) is asking for trouble that no one will ever want to fix.

Comment: I have not investigated all the conditions involved in detail. This is not the point of my answer. The point is to avoid having 2^7 = 128 if-else-cases for all combined options. And btw.: you can read chained ternary expressions from left to right.

Comment: The solution is most definitely **not** inlining the same 2^7=128 cases by swapping the `if` for a ternary (which is functionally equivalent and does nothing to simplify the 2^7=128 logical outcomes).

Comment: The problem is that he is assigning all the values at once and must therefore subdivide the cases so that the conditions relating to all the assigned properties match. This results in more cases than treating the properties separately. This is at least what his code snippet suggests.

Comment: Your justification for why the ternary shortens the code is not fair. `if(x) { result.R = "a" } else { result.R = "b" }` is the _actual_ equivalent, which is much shorter than the example where you've been copy-pasting constructors for no good reason. And it's barely longer than your ternary example (but pedantically, it still is longer). The ternary suggestion also falls apart when you consider that several options interact with one another (as is obvious from the question body), which massively complicates the logic to a point where inline ternaries may end up doing more harm than good.

Comment: In short, your "too long" example is built in a way that it facilitates different scenario's for `x + y + !z` and `x + y + z`, so that the value of `z` influences the outcome of evaluating `x` and `y` too. Your "ternary" example completely omits that point, and its outcome of `z` is decided by `z` alone (regardless of the values of `x` and `y`). **These are not equivalent examples**.

Comment: In my long example `x` influences only `R`, `y` only `S` and `z` only `T`. So they are equivalent. But since the OP never really asked a question (its me who edited and added a question, but it's only a guess), we don't know what his problem really is and what he is expecting as an answer.

Comment: That is flatout incorrect. You are supplying a **different magic string** (which just happens to have the same value). Consider the case of `x + y + !z` rendering `new Result() { R = "potato", S = "carrot", T = "cucumber" }` and the case of `x + y + z` rendering `new Result() { R = "Frodo", S = "Gandalf", T = "Aragorn" }`. The only different input value is `z`, yet **all** values are now different. Just because you chose to repeat the same magical string values does not mean that your example isn't unnecessarily bloated and functionally different (as a general example) from the ternary example

Comment: It is pointless to debate on these details, since we don't know the OP's intended logic anyway. My point is that if the values are not interdependent, then the code could be simplified. Btw.: I removed the magic strings.